# Batch file appears not to run and shuts down immediately

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a batch file with the following code:

```
set dirA=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\In
set dirE=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\OutPut
set dirC=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\Processed
```

The batch file does not run and shuts down immediately and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: what do you expect the batch file to do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?
Actually, the batch file kinda works: it sets environment variables dirA, dirE and dirC, then it's done and closes. You didn't code it to echo anything, so it just sets these variables and exits.

Comment: FYI, if you `Set` a variable within a batch file, that variable is assigned only within the context of that batch file. Once you exit that context those variables become undefined, _(they're gone)_! If you wish to set variables to be used external to the context of the batch file, you could take a look at the `SetX` command or use a different alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you need to understand. When we set variables, we typically enclose them in double quotes in case there are whitespace, which after the whitespace, the next field is seen by `cmd` as a new command and you will get some errors you would not want, such as the infamous "Is not recognised as an internal command on batch file` error, so we would therefore rather do this:

```
set "dirA=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\In"
set "dirE=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\OutPut"
set "dirC=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\Processed"
```

The code then does exactly what you told it to do and that is to simply set variables `%dirA%` `%dirE%` and `%dirC%` with the respected values.

Now to see a result, you need to do something with those variables, perhaps we echo them?

```
@echo off
set "dirA=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\In"
set "dirE=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\OutPut"
set "dirC=C:\SE_BulkUnzipTarGzipFiles\WinRarSamples\Processed"
echo %dirA%
echo %dirE%
echo %dirC%
pause
```

Answer (score -2):

Your script runs, but it finishes almost immediately.

If you add a `pause` command at the end, the window will stay open until you press a key.